# Custom Fonts not working on local as well as live website on Firefox 8 hosted on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, iis-7, firefox-8

I have tried all the options to make the custom fonts work in Firefox 8.0...But they are not working at all.They are working on Firefox 7 and below and on all the other browsers as well(IE7,IE8,IE9,Safari,Chrome)

I've tried every possible option for MIME types:

```
woff (application/octet-stream)
woff (font/woff)
woff (application/x-font-woff)
```

but the result is the same...

font-face is not working at all for the font..My CSS is as follows:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'My Font';
    src: url('/Fonts/My Font-webfont.eot');
    src:url('/Fonts/My Font-webfont.eot?#iefix') 
    format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('/Fonts/My Font-webfont.woff') 
    format('woff'), 
    url('/Fonts/My Font-webfont.ttf') 
    format('truetype'), 
    url('/Fonts/gebooker-webfont.svg#My Font') 
    format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

All the fonts are served from the same domain on which the site is hosted..

Can anyone please suggest how to make the font working on Firefox 8?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are the commas and semicolons correct?

Answer (score 2):

Upload your font file to [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).
This will output all the different font types you need to get your custom font to work on all browsers that support CSS `@font-face`.